# Repair tear/hole on EVA sole

Tags: shoes, repair

My shoe got caught by a closing aluminum door and the edge of the door punched a hole on the [EVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylene-vinyl_acetate) sole.

[image: Puncture damage in sole]

What would be the best way to fix it? Would rubber cement be a good patch for this?

**UPDATE**

Used a PU sealant, cut off the excess, and smoothed it out with some sandpaper.

[image]
[image]

Comment: A torn spacesuit is a serious problem - do not use it for any further Extra Vehicular Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White polyurethane (PU) sealant is a good candidate and should yield a nearly invisible repair. It's not foam but of a similar softness and flexibility as foam so there is little danger of mechanical separation during use.

**Instructions:**

1. Clean the hole thoroughly inside to de-grease it. I usually use ethanol. In your case a cotton bud would make a good cleaning tool.
2. Push in the tip of a [sealant gun](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=sealant%20gun) into the hole and fill it with PU sealant. It's fine if some comes out the hole, at least you'll know it's full …
3. Use a plastic scraper to remove excess material and create a smooth exterior. An old credit card works well.
4. Let it cure for a few days. PU sealant hardens by reaction with air humidity at a rate of 1-3 mm/day.

**Disadvantage:** If you don't have it around, most likely you'll have to buy a full 300 ml cartridge of PU sealant. It's universally useful and lasts ca. 6 months once the cartridge is open, so not a big deal.

**Variation:** Note that there are also PU based construction glues. These are a higher strength material but also become harder than sealants, so I think that a sealant mimics the mechanical properties of the foam better in this case. Anyway, both would do.

**Source:** Educated guess from experience. I glued maybe 8 shoe soles back in place over the years, some with a foam backing. And PU sealant / glue worked best.

Comment: That's what I used! Patched it up in May '17; updated the post with pics.

Answer (score 1):

Hot glue sticks well to EVA foam... because it's made from EVA!

Comment: Crap. I used a sealant (http://www.magnaprime.com.ph/products/handy-fix/2-handy-fix/) because I couldn't find colored hot glue. Apparently, I can melt crayons together with the hot glue (http://www.observationsblog.com/sciencetechnologyexperiments/make-your-own-color-hot-glue-sticks)

Comment: But would hot glue have the same (or close to same) flex/bounce/rigidity as EVA soles?

Comment: Well, it's flexible, but isn't foam, so a large quantity might affect the feel, I suppose. Never heard of the crayon thing...

Answer (score 0):

A moldable, silicone rubber based adhesive, such as one made from Formerol, might be a viable option here

Comment: Nice! Wish I saw this sooner!